# Use Blob in datastore but namespace not known by Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, rpc

I have a class that I like to store in Google App Engine DataStore like:

```
@Entity
public class Game {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     private Date latestUpdate;
     private short x, y;
     private List<String> players;
     private Blob board;
...
```

But when trying to serialize it via the 'RPC Service' wizard in
Eclipse i get code that can not find the 'com.google.appengine'
namespace.

**Anyone have any clue how the send Blob, byte[] or int[] from the app
engine to an Android application???**

Generics (like List< String >) I get to work but I'd prefer not to do
the conversion all the time from byte[].

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine [RPC Wizard](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc.html) relies on [GWT RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) to do the marshaling/unmarshaling.

RequestFactory is quite limited and provides only a few [transportable types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable). Arrays and GAE classes are unfortunately not among them.

Comment: Yes, true true Peter...I solved my problem by transforming my array, of type char[], to a String... beautiful...no...does it get the job done...yes.